# Pytorch: Node2Vec: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to run Node2Vec from the torch_geometric.nn library. For reference, I am following [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX9YY.png) example.

While running the train() function I keep getting `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`.

I am using `torch version 1.6.0` with `CUDA 10.1` and the latest versions of `torch-scatter`,`torch-sparse`,`torch-cluster`, `torch-spline-conv` and `torch-geometric`.

Here is the detailed error:

[Part 1 of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX9YY.png)

[Part 2 of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPYEZ.png)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to `torch.ops.torch_cluster.random_walk` returning a tuple instead of an array/tensor. I fixed it by using replacing the functions `pos_sample` and `neg_sample` in the `torch_geometric.nn.Node2Vec` with these.

```
def pos_sample(self, batch):
    batch = batch.repeat(self.walks_per_node)
    rowptr, col, _ = self.adj.csr()
    rw = random_walk(rowptr, col, batch, self.walk_length, self.p, self.q)
    if not isinstance(rw, torch.Tensor):
        rw = rw[0]

    walks = []
    num_walks_per_rw = 1 + self.walk_length + 1 - self.context_size
    for j in range(num_walks_per_rw):
        walks.append(rw[:, j:j + self.context_size])
    return torch.cat(walks, dim=0)


def neg_sample(self, batch):
    batch = batch.repeat(self.walks_per_node * self.num_negative_samples)

    rw = torch.randint(self.adj.sparse_size(0),
                       (batch.size(0), self.walk_length))
    rw = torch.cat([batch.view(-1, 1), rw], dim=-1)

    walks = []
    num_walks_per_rw = 1 + self.walk_length + 1 - self.context_size
    for j in range(num_walks_per_rw):
        walks.append(rw[:, j:j + self.context_size])
    return torch.cat(walks, dim=0)
```

Refer to PyTorch Node2Vec [documentation](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/nn/models/node2vec.html).